# WPF: ContextMenu in templated ListBox Item (InvalidCastException)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I'm trying to add a context menu to a ListBoxItem. I'm using ListBox.ItemTemplate and DataTemplate (with a Grid) to define the layout of the item and the ListBoxItem is styled.

In a search that this should be the way to go:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Rename" Click="Rename_Click" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

But this throws an `XamlParseException/InvalidCastException` saying

> Couldn't cast an object of the type
>   System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem to the type
>   System.Windows.Controls.Grid

I tried adding the context menu to the Grid in the `ItemTemplate`, but then it only works when you click on one of the elements in the Grid (there is some empty space) (or if I add a background to the Grid, but that overrides/"covers" the styling, for hover & selected, of the Item itself)

I can't find any similar issues when searching, and I can't figure out the logic of the Exception..

Comment: Can you pls post the code for the ItemTemplate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could overcome this by defining the `ContextMenu` as a resource:

```
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="cm">
                <MenuItem Header="Rename" Click="Rename_Click" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            ...
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks! Any idea on why it didn't work the other way (which is the way that it's done in all of the samples I found)?

Answer (score -1):

Use the `TargetType="ListBoxItem"` string of code. Because the coding langauge needs to know the Listbox!

Comment: Not sure on what you mean!
I am using `TargetType="ListBoxItem"‽